# Am I actually calling ctor and initializing the vtable on an pointer to an object? C++

Tags: c++, constructor, dereference

I feel a little dumb for asking this but I have a situation where I cannot use the new keyword. I need to make sure the constructor is being called for the object pointed to by the variable Utf8Buffer, an example lies below.

```
Utf8String * pUtf8Buffer;
    void Initialize(void * stringbuffer, size_t bufferlen)
    {
        pUtf8Buffer = (Utf8String*)this->pMemMan->AllocMem(sizeof(Utf8String));
        //In the line below am I calling ctor of the object pointed to by the Utf8Buffer
        //I specifically need ctor to be called on this object to initialize the vtable
        (*pUtf8Buffer) = Utf8String(stringbuffer, bufferlen);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think custom allocators will call constructor by default. It's the same for `malloc` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instead need [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new):

```
pUtf8Buffer = (Utf8String*)this->pMemMan->AllocMem(sizeof(Utf8String));

new (pUtf8Buffer) Utf8String(stringbuffer, bufferlen);
```

And of course if the constructor throws, you need to release the memory.  So add a try/catch block, which with a little more type safety looks like this:

```
void* pRawBuffer = this->pMemMan->AllocMem(sizeof(Utf8String));

try {
    pUtf8Buffer = new (pRawBuffer) Utf8String(stringbuffer, bufferlen);
} catch (...) {
    pUtf8Buffer = nullptr;
    this->pMemMan->ReleaseMem(pRawBuffer);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: I actually cannot use try and catch yet either, this was just a copy and paste example not the actual code obviously I wanna check to make sure the memory allocation succeeded in my example. Thankfully in my  implementations the constructors are guaranteed to not throw any errors. Thank you, I never knew of placement new. Using the method I used does not initialize the vtables and yours does.